# Logo and navbar one to one

Tags: html, css

I tried everything I know nad nothing helped me 0.0 . I do a research but cant find whats the problem in my code.

I want Navbar and logo to be on the same line :/
http://prntscr.com/b0z7sp
And here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>ООУ "Јосип Броз Тито"</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stilovi.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id = "glavendrzac">

    <div id = "logoimeni">
    <div class = "logopozicija">
        <img src="sliki/logo.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class = "menidologo">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Почетна</a></li>
            <li><a href="kontakt.php">Контакт</a></li>
            <li><a href="novsti.php">Новости</a></li>
            <li><a href="korisnici.php">Корисници</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "sliki">

        <div class = "profesor">
            <img src="sliki/profesor.png" width="270px"; height="450px";/>
        </div>
        <div id = "tabla">
            <div class = "tablatekst">
                <h2>Јосип Броз Тито</h1>
                Училиштето Јосип Броз Тито го добило името по претседателот на Југославија 'Јосип Броз Тито'. Училиштето најпрво се наоѓало во близина на сегашното а сега на тоа место
                се наоѓа спротската сала 'Филип II Македонски". Оваа спортска сала ја користат учениците за часот по Фискултура, а во неа исто така се одржуваат некои спортски
                натпревари и тренинзи. Во 1980 година старото училиште изгорело па е изградено ново училиште и во негов состав влегуваат:<br>
                - Самото училиште<br>
                - Едно игралиште<br>
                - Една спортска сала<br>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
//
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is CSS

```
#glavendrzac 
{
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#sliki 
{
    border-top: 2px solid black;
} 
.profesor 
{
    float: left;
    margin-top:60px;
}
#tabla 
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: url("sliki/tabla.png");
    background-size: cover;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.tablatekst 
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: bold;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.logopozicija
{
    width: 450px;
}

.menidologo
{
    width: 600;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.menidologo ul
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#logoimeni
{
    z-index: 1;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried float: left on the navigation urls?

Comment: You should wrap #logopozicija and #menidologo in a parent div and then use the CSS float property on them:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp
https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: ohh thanks. i am big.. xD Its working now TY :DDD <3

Comment: I like inline block over float in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

HTML :

```
 <div id="logoimeni">
    <div class="logopozicija">
      <img src="sliki/logo.png" />
       <div class="menidologo">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Почетна</a></li>
        <li><a href="kontakt.php">Контакт</a></li>
        <li><a href="novsti.php">Новости</a></li>
        <li><a href="korisnici.php">Корисници</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS :

```
.menidologo ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
}

.menidologo ul li {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For .logopozicija use float:left 
For .menidolog use float:right

Comment: Try use float:left on #logoimeni with width:100%; height:auto;